# Installshield 2010, Selecting to NOT install a feature, and it still attempts to install it

Tags: installshield, installshield-2010

While using installshield 2010, I give the user the ability to install or not install two of three features during the installation process.

If the user chooses the "complete" install, everything installs fine.
If the user chooses to NOT install a feature, the installer still thinks that they are trying to install it, and does not find it, and throws an error.

Does anyone have an idea of why this could be occurring?

Thanks,
btg

Comment: Hi btg, is this an MSI project, or an InstallScript one?  Can you enable logging (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/223300) and paste info from the log about the error?

Comment: Does this happen during an MSI upgrade? If it does, try checking the MigrateFeatureStates action in the installation log. Perhaps the feature states are migrated from the old version.

Answer (score 0):

what is the error the installer is giving.
Check if ADDLOCAL property is set in the property table. If the value set is ALL then the installer will try to installer all the features which are included for installation.

If for different users you need to pass this product create transforms with  which all features are needed to be installed.